# DVD drive not detected in Ubuntu, Windows and BIOS

Tags: boot, dvd

I installed Ubuntu 4 days ago on my system and since then my PC seems to be ruined. Windows boot time has increased like 4 or 5 times. Ubuntu takes about 2 minutes to boot and worst of all, my DVD drive has vanished from all OS as well as BIOS. 
Please help me.

Note: I had applied the changes in the tutorial in the following link.
http://itsfoss.com/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-14-04/

Comment: Well to me a 2 min boot on ubuntu is pretty good. How fast would you say windows is now?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your optical drive can not be seen in BIOS that can mean two: it's dead or it's disconnected(or both at the same time).

Also "TO DO" list's advices could not dramatically decrease your boot up time because they are not related to such things.

Indeed two minutes sounds reasonable which makes me thin you have HDD drive in there not SDD, don't you? If so I would recommend to look at using SSD in the future if you care about performance.